# Find duration on overlapping time segments in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, overlapping

I am working on building a query report where i have multiple types of segment with priority ranking on one table and second table with all types of segment with date, time etc. (as shown below) The duration for lower ranked segment during overlap should not be considered.

Please help me as I am unable to figure out query and get the duration of segment excluding the overlap based on ranking

table_Rank

```
Rank     Code
1        x
2        y
3        z
4        a  
5        b
6        c
7        d
8        r
9        f
```

Table_Segments

```
Code    Date    Start Time  End Time    Duration
a   18-Jul-15   17:30        17:45      0:15
c   18-Jul-15   18:00        19:00      1:00
y   18-Jul-15   18:45        19:00      0:15
a   18-Jul-15   20:15        20:20      0:05
b   18-Jul-15   23:45        1:00       1:15
z   19-Jul-15   0:30         1:15       0:45
f   19-Jul-15   2:00         3:00       1:00
```

- Table With Ranks = Table_Rank
- Table With Data = Table_Segments

What i am trying to achieves is, in an overlap situation overlap span should be considered for code with higher rank.
e.g. 
    `Code   Date      Start Time    End Time   Duration`

```
     b    18-Jul-15   23:45          1:00       1:15
     z    19-Jul-15    0:30          1:15       0:45
```

The actual duration output for **b** should 45 minutes as it has a lower rank compared to **z** and **z** should be 45 minutes

Comment: Please edit your question and (1) tag the question with the database you are actually using.  (2) Provide desired results.  You might also want to set up a SQL Fiddle, because that will help anyone attempting to answer the question.

Comment: I dont see any quertion there.

Comment: Hello,I added updates to my query. I am just looking for a SQL query that will help me build a report

Comment: Desired output for given data is missing. It's impossible to guess what logic you're trying to apply in query